# Sage plot slope field and differential equation

Tags: python, matplotlib, differential-equations, sage

I am attempting to plot the slope field, and several unique solutions in sage notebook, but my slope field does not match the solutions.

```
c = var('c')
y = (ln(x)+c)/x
show(y)
p1 = plot_slope_field( y, (x,0,5), (c,-5,5))

for i in range(-5,5):
    p1 = p1 + plot(y(c=i),x,0,5, ymin=-5, ymax=5)
p1
```

[image: plot]p1

I would expect the slope field to approximate the slope of the near-by functions, but they don't appear to match at all.

Comment: You are plotting slope field against the function itself.  The heights of your functions are very closely aligned with the slope of the little lines.  What you want is to plot the solutions of an ODE that those slopes represent!  Let me see if I can cook something up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slopes should not contain the integration constants. The slope field is the vector field `(1,f(x,y))` for the differential equation `y'=f(x,y)`. Thus you need to find the ODE for your family of functions by eliminating the constant `c`.

For the equation

```
y = (ln(x)+c)/x
```

the isolation of the constant `c` gives

```
c = xy - ln(x)
```

and the derivative equation / implicit ODE

```
0 = xy' + y - 1/x
```

Thus the slope field should be for the slopes

```
y' = f(x,y) = -y/x + 1/(x*x)
```

---

```
x = var('x')
y = var('y')
c = var('c')
ysol = (ln(x)+c)/x
show(ysol)
p1 = plot_slope_field( -y/x+1/(x*x), (x,0,5), (y,-5,5))

for i in range(-5,5):
    p1 = p1 + plot(ysol(c=i),x,0,5, ymin=-5, ymax=5)
p1
```

[image: slope field by sage server]

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake, and @kcrisman pointed it out as well, I forgot to differentiate (linearize) the function for the slope field.

this fixes it:

```
p1 = plot_slope_field( diff(y), (x,0,5), (c,-5,5))
```

and we get:

[image: proper_field]

Comment: No, the image does not look right, where the slopes intersect the solutions they are often rather transversal and not tangent.